# How to enable libx264 in ffmpeg in openwrt

Tags: ffmpeg, openwrt, libx264

when I run 'ffmpeg -encoders=libx264',
it shows:

```
Unknown encoder 'libx264'
```

I have installed 'ffmpeg' on Openwrt. How i can enable this. Please guide me

Comment: Do you want to encode a video with libx264? -c:v libx264

Comment: Sorry but why exactly you intend to do with ffmpeg in a router's OS/firmware?

Comment: Besides, support for 'h264' isn't something you just enable... Again, it's a router's firmware and it has to be **compiled** with such support in mind: https://forum.openwrt.org/t/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-h-264-support/116554

Comment: i have installed openwrt on raspbery pi. i want to store camera streaming into filesystem. for that purpose i am using ffmpeg. my camera supports h.264. when i run ffmpeg command. it give errors. but when i change enocder setting from camera. use mjpeg instead of h.264, it works fine

Comment: Please Edit your question to make it more clear, rather than adding comments.